# JSF: FacesMessage being displayed twice

Tags: jsf-2, facescontext

Here's the scenario.  In my managed bean, I create a new FacesMessage object and add it to the FacesContext, without associating it with any UI component, like so:

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage();
message.setSummary("Hi there!");
context.addMessage(null, message);
```

In my xhtml page, I output my message like so:

```
<h:messages id="someId" globalOnly="true" showSummary="true" showDetail="false" styleClass="startUpMessages"/>
```

However, the generated html displays the summary of the message twice, like so:

```
<ul id="mainForm:someId" class="startUpMessages"><li>   Hi there! </li><li> Hi there! </li></ul>
<ul id="javax_faces_developmentstage_messages" title="Project Stage[Development]: Unhandled Messages"></ul>
```

Can anyone explain this behaviour?

Comment: are you sure that your code for adding messages not running several times ? place simple print outs .....

Comment: I've placed a printout in my managed bean next to the FacesMessage creation as you suggested.  The printout only appears once.

Comment: Just curious, if you do context.addMessage("test", message); and globalOnly="false" does it remove the other message ?

Comment: I just tried your suggestion, with and without a UI component with id="test".  The generated html is the same as above.

Comment: What JSF impl/version? What servletcontainer impl/version? Is it a servlet or portlet environment?

Comment: This app was built with JSF 2.0, with servlet container version 2.5, in a servlet environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this issue was caused by an oversight in a phase listener in the application, that wasn't mentioned in the question.

This phase listener was designed to solve an issue with persisting FacesMessages across two adjacent requests, in one particular instance of the application.  It would store all of the FacesMessages that were created in a request scoped bean into the session temporarily.

However, the phase listener was mistakingly implemented to execute during every request.  So FacesMessages that were created in session scoped beans (like the one in question) ended up being duplicated, which explains why I was seeing the summary of the message displayed twice.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your Web.xml. 
Change `PROJECT_STAGE` from `Development` to `Production`

```
<!-- Web application context parameters -->
<context-param>
    <description>One of Production, Development, UnitTest, SystemTest, Extension
        Default is Production.
    </description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Production</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: That only hides the unhandled messages. In OP's case the duplicate message isn't an unhandled message.